# Python Django: button assign variable from array in for loop per line per click

Tags: python, django, loops, for-loop, variables

Is it possible in Python/Django to assign variable from array line each time I click on submit button and display result in same page?
Using a counter or other idea.

For example:

```py
array=[1,2,3,4,5]
var = 0
for i in array:
   if button is clicked:
      var = array[i]
   endif
endfor
```

And each time I click on the button, the `var` value is incremented:

First time I click `var = 1`

Next click I click `var = 2`

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you want to store this data? If so where? Otherwise this would best be done in Javascript.

Comment: hello, thank you for feedback
yes, each time I click, the data (current value of var) is stored in database
then, next click I would like to stay in the same page and var is incremented by clicking

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/how-to-get-mouse-clicks-with-python/) in order to record mouse input in python

Then update your code, the **for loop** will iterate too quickly on the five elements, **you will not have the time to perform a click.**

You could try this, but better solutions can be found:

```py
    array=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    var = 0
    for i in array:
        while button is not clicked: # wait input
            var = array[i] # Set your variable
            # do what you want with your variable
            continue # go to next iteration
```

Comment: hello, thank you for feedback.
Already tried, its looping without end..